# ¿Por qué la función replace de TS no está actuando como espero?

Tags: angular, ts

Sea la **función** siguiente:

```
  formatLatexResponse(input: string): string {
    // Reemplazar "\" por "\\" en toda la cadena
    let formattedInput = input.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");

    // Agregar "<br><br>" por cada línea en blanco o por cada salto de línea
    formattedInput = formattedInput.replace(/\n\s*\n/g, "<br><br>");
    formattedInput = formattedInput.replace(/\n/g, '<br><br>');

    return formattedInput;
}
```

Sea el **string** siguiente:

```
input: string = `Para plantear el sistema de ecuaciones, definimos las incógnitas como:
  $x$: número de hectáreas de trigo
  $y$: número de hectáreas de maíz
  
  Dado que el agricultor ha sembrado un total de $x$ hectáreas de trigo y $y$ hectáreas de maíz, la primera ecuación se obtiene sumando ambas cantidades y debe ser igual a la cantidad total de hectáreas sembradas, que llamaremos $T$:
  \[ x + y = T \]`;
```

¿Por qué "x + y = T" aparece como "[ x + y = T ]" a comienzo de línea en lugar de como "x + y = T" centrado?

Para que tengáis contexto, estoy trabajando en una APP mayor y esta función forma parte de lo que será una especie de traductor entre el lenguaje que usarán los usuarios y el lenguaje latex. Dado que en latex se usa mucho el carácter "\" como carácter especial, pero en TS (la APP se desarrolla en Angular y se usa mathjax-angular, luego se usa TS) "\" es el carácter de escape (así creo que se denomina), es necesario "escapar" el carácter de escape y, en consecuencia, cambiar cada "\" por "\\".

[image: img01]

Como puede observarse, no aparece la ecuación centrada en la última línea, sino que la ecuación está entre corchetes y a comienzo de línea.

Resumiendo el **problema**: no logro que el texto escrito en latex, tras los reemplazos pertinentes, se visualice como es de esperar en el texto HTML.

Comment: Hola Sergio, te sugiero que elimines la imagen que adjuntaste y agregues su texto en la pregunta, las imágenes solo para mostrar imágenes ;)

Comment: No sería más bien que no se muestra en el HTML como debe?

Comment: Marce, me parece importante que se visualice el resultado obtenido. Por eso la imagen. Me parece mucho más claro así que metiendo más texto plano a la respuesta.

Comment: René, tienes razón. Me expresé mal. Me refiero a la visualización en el HTML. Ahora lo corrijo. Gracias

Comment: El error es que input no tiene ningun "\" asi que cuando le pasas `/\\/g` al replace pues input queda igual. Osea `\[ x + y = T \]` esto no sirve pa poner "\"en un string porque como tu dices "\" es una secuencia de escape. debes porner \\ x + y = T \\. Dale console.log al input y veras que no tiene backslash.

Comment: Podría ser lo que comenta @clay o si es un problema del HTML, tal vez tengas que agregarle un `div`, `span`, etc. con alguna clase que centre la ecuación.

Comment: Clay, creo que entiendo lo que dices. El string "\\[ x + y = T \\]" no contiene estrictamente el carácter "\", pues este es un carácter de escape. Pero entonces, ¿qué opciones tengo para cambiar "\" como carácter de escape a "\\" como doble carácter normal?

Comment: como te dije en elanterior comentario, debes poner "\\" porque "\\" en javascrip es "\" , mirate esta tabla. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#notaci%C3%B3n_de_escape

Comment: Pero Clay, entiendo que la solución que me das es para modificar manualmente el string en particular. Pero lo que quiero lograr es definir una función que haga dicha sustitución de manera automática para cualquier string. En el "replace" ya uso "\\" y no funciona porque la barra invertida se ignora al ser carácter de escape

Comment: creo que no me estas entendiendo, tu string input de donde viene ? ajax ? textinput?... porque lo que parece es que lo estas ecribiendo a **mano** en el codigo y en ese caso es en el que debe porner \\ para que cuando se lo pases a la funcion replace ella lo remplace por el \\\\.

Comment: El ejemplo que proporciono es evidentemente hecho a mano. Pero el texto que se usará una vez bien definida la función "formatLatexResponse" se introducirá de forma dinámica. Para meternos más a fondo en el tema, os detallo que la app hace uso de chat-gpt. Este se usa para ciertos fines y sus Strings no consideran el caracter de escape "\", es decir, devuelve "\" en lugar de escaparlo y devolver "\\". Por eso es necesario duplicar las barras invertidas. De hecho, el ejemplo en cuestión es uno de los textos devueltos por chat-gpt.

Comment: Siendo asi, creo que no debes hacer nada porque me imagino que chatgpt te da el texto en un JSON y de ser asi, este texto ya vendria con el "\\". Si no es asi, deberias editar la pregunta con el texto que chatgpt retorna y en que formato lo hace.